# structure used in そんなもんだって

Tags: grammar

In this sentence:

> おまえ、本気で信じてるのか？あいつが幽霊だか生き霊だか、何か、**そんなもんだって**

could someone explain to me the structure used in そんなもんだって ?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I’m not hundred percent to be trusted on this either but here’s what I know:

The translation would be something like:

> Do you actually believe it? The thing about them being a ghost, vengeful spirit or something like that?

Here そんなもんだって equals そんな+もの+だ+って
in which もん is the abbreviated version of もの; because that’s just how japanese people pronounce もの and の sometimes. like the same way のだ is turned into んだ. With this, the meaning for そんなものだ would be “they are something like that”.

As for って, it can be an abbreviation for と、という、ということ (or というもの or というの) and some time even the particles that might come with it. Here’s an example from Tae Kim's book:

> 来年留学するというのは、智子のこと？
>  the studying abroad next year thing; is that Tomoko?
>
> 来年留学するって、智子のこと？ 
>  the studying abroad next year thing; is that Tomko?

so here as well, そんなものだって would be : そんなものだとはwhich can be interpreted as a quote for 信じる.

> そんなものだと本気で信じてるのか？
> Do you actually believe that they are something like that?

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I think it'd be そんなものだと.

Comment: sorry, you’re right. I was too carried away by the more complex phrases.